# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class “xxx.xxx.MainActivityTest.java” on path: DexPathList

Tags: gradle, adb, android-espresso, fastlane

I am trying to run an instrumentation test (Espresso) in the emulator using the CLI, to generate screenshots of our app with fastlane / screen grab. The app is IONIC Cordova based.

When performing my Espresso tests from within Android Studio it is logging:

```
Testing started at 16:34 ...

07/30 16:34:29: Launching MainActivityTest
$ adb push /Users/administrator/Jenkins/workspace/generatescreenshots/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/de.konzeptix.test.app
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/de.konzeptix.test.app"
Success


$ adb push /Users/administrator/Jenkins/workspace/generatescreenshots/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/de.konzeptix.test.app.test
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/de.konzeptix.test.app.test"
Success


Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest' de.konzeptix.test.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Tests ran to completion.
```

If I try it this way, my test class is found, and performs as intended.

I have to work on the command line, not inside Android Studio though, because the whole process is started and run through our CI Server (Jenkins).

So no 'instant run' to disable, and no 'clean and rebuild', to solve this problem as proposed in several other questions...

If I try calling my tests on the cli, my test class cannot be found.
Here is the output of the process:

```
00:03:06.842 +----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.843 |                                  Detected Values from './fastlane/Screengrabfile'                                  |
00:03:06.844 +----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.845 | app_package_name           | de.konzeptix.test.app                                                                 |
00:03:06.845 | tests_package_name         | de.konzeptix.test.app.test                                                            |
00:03:06.846 | use_tests_in_classes       | ["de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java"]                                  |
00:03:06.847 | app_apk_path               | ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
00:03:06.847 | tests_apk_path             | ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
00:03:06.848 | locales                    | ["de-DE"]                                                                             |
00:03:06.849 | launch_arguments           | ["'shot0 topsBtn'", " 'shot1 articlesBtn'", " 'shot2 eventsBtn'"]                     |
00:03:06.850 | device_type                | phone                                                                                 |
00:03:06.850 | clear_previous_screenshots | true                                                                                  |
00:03:06.851 +----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.852 
00:03:06.852 
00:03:06.853 +-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.854 |                                            Summary for screengrab 2.99.1                                            |
00:03:06.869 +-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.870 | android_home                | /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk                                              |
00:03:06.870 | locales                     | ["de-DE"]                                                                             |
00:03:06.870 | clear_previous_screenshots  | true                                                                                  |
00:03:06.870 | output_directory            | fastlane/metadata/android                                                             |
00:03:06.871 | skip_open_summary           | false                                                                                 |
00:03:06.871 | app_package_name            | de.konzeptix.test.app                                                                 |
00:03:06.871 | tests_package_name          | de.konzeptix.test.app.test                                                            |
00:03:06.872 | use_tests_in_classes        | ["de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java"]                                  |
00:03:06.872 | launch_arguments            | ["'shot0 topsBtn'", " 'shot1 articlesBtn'", " 'shot2 eventsBtn'"]                     |
00:03:06.872 | test_instrumentation_runner | android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner                                        |
00:03:06.872 | ending_locale               | en-US                                                                                 |
00:03:06.873 | app_apk_path                | ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
00:03:06.873 | tests_apk_path              | ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
00:03:06.873 | device_type                 | phone                                                                                 |
00:03:06.874 | exit_on_test_failure        | true                                                                                  |
00:03:06.874 | reinstall_app               | false                                                                                 |
00:03:06.874 +-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
00:03:06.874 
00:03:06.949 Clearing phoneScreenshots within fastlane/metadata/android
00:03:06.951 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
00:03:06.960 ▸ List of devices attached
00:03:06.966 ▸ emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
00:03:06.974 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE
00:03:06.981 ▸ /sdcard
00:03:06.988 Cleaning screenshots on device
00:03:07.000 ls: /sdcard/de.konzeptix.test.app/screengrab: No such file or directory
00:03:07.001 Exit status: 1
00:03:07.021 ls: /data/data/de.konzeptix.test.app/app_screengrab: Permission denied
00:03:07.022 Exit status: 1
00:03:07.025 Validating app APK
00:03:07.026 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.1/aapt dump permissions ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
00:03:07.032 ▸ package: de.konzeptix.test.app
00:03:07.036 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD'
00:03:07.040 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK'
00:03:07.045 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
00:03:07.049 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
00:03:07.052 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION'
00:03:07.054 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
00:03:07.057 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
00:03:07.059 ▸ uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
00:03:07.062 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ'
00:03:07.065 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE'
00:03:07.067 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS'
00:03:07.070 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT'
00:03:07.072 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE'
00:03:07.075 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT'
00:03:07.077 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE'
00:03:07.080 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
00:03:07.081 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE'
00:03:07.083 ▸ uses-permission: name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'
00:03:07.084 ▸ permission: de.konzeptix.test.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
00:03:07.086 ▸ uses-permission: name='de.konzeptix.test.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'
00:03:07.087 Installing app APK
00:03:07.088 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
00:03:07.447 ▸ Success
00:03:07.449 Installing tests APK
00:03:07.450 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
00:03:08.115 ▸ Success
00:03:08.122 Granting the permission necessary to change locales on the device
00:03:08.124 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant de.konzeptix.test.app android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
00:03:08.302 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
00:03:08.328 ▸ 28
00:03:08.349 Granting the permissions necessary to access device external storage
00:03:08.350 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant de.konzeptix.test.app android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
00:03:08.413 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant de.konzeptix.test.app android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
00:03:08.462 Running tests for locale: de-DE
00:03:08.464 $ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
00:03:08.467 -e testLocale de_DE \
00:03:08.468 -e endingLocale en_US \
00:03:08.468 -e class de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java \
00:03:08.468 -e 'shot0 topsBtn' -e  'shot1 articlesBtn' -e  'shot2 eventsBtn' \
00:03:08.469 de.konzeptix.test.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
00:03:09.116 ▸ de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java:
00:03:09.123 ▸ Error in de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java:
00:03:09.130 ▸ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java
00:03:09.137 ▸ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
00:03:09.143 ▸ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
00:03:09.150 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
00:03:09.157 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
00:03:09.164 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
00:03:09.172 ▸ at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
00:03:09.179 ▸ at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
00:03:09.186 ▸ at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
00:03:09.193 ▸ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
00:03:09.207 ▸ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
00:03:09.211 ▸ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
00:03:09.214 ▸ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
00:03:09.216 ▸ ... 8 more
00:03:09.274 ▸ Time: 0.014
00:03:09.281 ▸ There was 1 failure:
00:03:09.287 ▸ 1) de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java
00:03:09.294 ▸ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java
00:03:09.301 ▸ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
00:03:09.309 ▸ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
00:03:09.315 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:72)
00:03:09.322 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
00:03:09.330 ▸ at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:789)
00:03:09.334 ▸ at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:539)
00:03:09.338 ▸ at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:382)
00:03:09.342 ▸ at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
00:03:09.346 ▸ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.konzeptix.test.app.test.MainActivityTest.java" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app.test-uaWS_ap-9oK2KRdJOAlBJg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/de.konzeptix.test.app-BROFUx3GSnQkL4K7pknnyw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
00:03:09.354 ▸ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
00:03:09.358 ▸ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
00:03:09.361 ▸ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
00:03:09.361 ▸ ... 8 more
00:03:09.363 ▸ FAILURES!!!
00:03:09.364 ▸ Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

I suppose what shows up in the Android log makes the difference (**adb push**, **adb shell pm install**)

Can somebody please explain to me, what exactly is done there?

Answer (score 0):

As the fastlane screengrab installs both apps onto the device and I cannot clearly see any major differences to the Android Studio process of installing and running the instrumentation tests, I tried to use the other option of fastlane screengrab *use_tests_in_packages* instead of *use_tests_in_class*, which translates into the cli call

```
$ /Users/administrator/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
-e testLocale de_DE \
-e endingLocale en_US \
-e package de.konzeptix.test.app.test \
-e shot0 topsBtn -e shot1 articlesBtn -e shot2 eventsBtn -e shot3 galleriesBtn -e shot4 productsBtn -e shot5 faqBtn -e shot6 companyBtn -e shot7 contactsBtn \
de.konzeptix.test.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

using *-e package* instead of *-e class*.

For some weird reason, this works.